# A result of Erdős on increasing multiplicative functions

Tags: number-theory, reference-request

Erdős proved that if $f(n)$ is a monotone increasing function from the natural numbers to the positive reals, and $f(n)$ is completely multiplicative, then there exists some constant $C$ such that $f(n)=n^C$ for all $n$.

I have not been able to find a nice proof of this online and was hoping someone could provide a proof.

Comment: "A result of Erdös" is probably not a good title, given the number of results due to Erdös. "A theorem of Euler", "A lemma of Gauss." =D

Answer (score 2):

(rant) This started off being a nice proof that contained the main ideas of what to do. However, because this site demands to be spoon fed answers, I had to fill in all of the nitty gritty details, which take up space. Now, this is not longer a nice proof, which makes me sad. Oh well.(rant over)

Now, suppose that the function is non-decreasing at some point. We have $ f(a) = f(b)$ for $a < b$. Taking $n$ large enough such that $ a^n < 2^k < 2^{k+1} < b^n$, since $ f(a^n) = f(b^n)$, we conclude that $ f( 2^k) = f(2^{k+1} )$, and thus $f(2) = 1 $. Similarly, we can show that $f(x) = 1$ for all $x$. Thus, the only non-decreasing function that is non-decreasing at some point, is $f(x) = 1$. This corresponds to $C = 0 $.

Henceforth, the function is strictly increasing.

Clearly, we must have $f(1) = 1$. Henceforth, we will ignore this value, mainly because I want to divide by $\ln f(a) \neq 0 $.

First, prove by contradiction (it is obvious) that (for $n>1$), $f(n) > 1$.

Second, consider $g(x) = \frac{ \ln f(a) } { \ln a} $. Prove by contradiction that $g(x)$ is a constant.

> Suppose not. Then, we have $a , b \neq 1 $ such that $ g(a) < g(b) $, or that $  \frac{ \ln f(a) } { \ln a} < \frac{ \ln f(b) } { \ln b }$.
>  Since $ f(b) > 1 $, thus $\ln f(b) > 0 $. Also, $\ln a > 0$, so we can divide and multiply respectively to conclude that
>  $$ 0 < \frac{ \ln f(a) } { \ln f(b) } < \frac{ \ln a} { \ln b}  $$
>  As such, there exist positive integers such that $ \frac{ \ln f(a) } { \ln f(b) } < \frac{ c}{d} < \frac{ \ln a} { \ln b} $.

(For you to do, almost immediate) Show that the function is not increasing on the points $ a^d, b^c$.

> The RHS inequality gives us $a^d < b^c$ and the LHS inequality gives us $ f(a ^d) > f(b^c)$. Hence, the function is not increasing.

Third, conclude that $g(x)$ is a constant, and thus $ f(a) = a^C$ for some constant $C$. Furthermore, $C>0$.

---

Comment: For the record, and then I will leave (and I cleaned all my other comments): your initial (not present as edited during grace period)  was something like "Hint: Consider $g(x) = \frac{ \ln f(a) } { \ln a} $. Prove by contradiction that $g(x)$ is a constant." Spoilered 'Suppose not.' " This is not a nice proof.

Comment: @quid For the record, I was in the midst of writing out the main steps. I wanted to check that spoiler works. It gets tricky with displaying equations in newline mode, which is why nothing else appeared.

Comment: @quid It is entirely appropriate to post a proof outline. This attitude that 1. OP deserves a full proof with all details and 2. An answerer, having provided a proof outline, is to be berated until a full proof is supplied, is frankly ridiculous.

Comment: This was unfortunate timing then, as my initial impression was formed based on this version. Sorry.  To avoid such problems in the future you might consider [using the sandbox on meta](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/4666/sandbox-for-drafts-of-long-complex-posts).

Answer (score 1):

Here's a proof I came up with.

Let $C=\log_2 f(2)$, note that $f(2)\geq 1$ and therefore $C\geq 0$. Proceed by induction: Suppose that $f(n)=n^C$, and $n\geq 2$, we will show that $f(n+1)=(n+1)^C$. Write $D=\log_{n+1} f(n+1)$, then $C\leq D$, otherwise for sufficiently large $k$ we will have that $f(n^k)>f((n+1)^k)$, which contradicts the assumption $f$ is increasing. On the other hand, $f(n^2)=f(n)f(n)=n^{2C}=(n^2)^C$, and since $n\geq 2$ we have that $n^2>n+1$. So for the same reason as before $D\leq C$, and therefore $D=C$.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what details are missing. $n^2=n\cdot n$, and $f$ is multiplicative.

Comment: I meant that by a logarithm of $f(n+1)$ and $f(n^2)$ the same reasoning used to conclude that $C\leq D$ can be used again to conclude the opposite inequality.

Comment: Simply find a sufficiently large $k$ such that $(n+1)^{Dk}>(n^2)^{Ck}$, which is impossible due to monotony.