# Optimal multiplying method

Tags: polynomials, arithmetic, computational-complexity, multiplicative-function

Karatsuba gave the optimal way for multiplying two polynomials of degree 1.
He reduced the number of multiplications from 4 to 3.

Let the imput for $f$ be the degree of a polynomial and the output the number of multiplications needed to multiply two such polynomials.

Thus

$$f(1) = 3$$

And by iterating

$$ f(2^n -1) =< 3^n$$

That is karatsuba's result.

What are the best ( lowest ) values for

$$f(2) = ??$$
$$f(3) = 9 ??$$
$$f(4) = ??$$
$$f(5) = ??$$
$$f(6)= ??$$
$$f(7)= ??$$

And how do these formula look like ?

Comment: Im not so familiar with tensors , rank etc so I write it like this. It can be stated better but that is beyond my skills.

Comment: Linked http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1888741/best-algoritm-for-multiplying-3-univariate-polynomials

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$f(2)$ seems to be $6$.

$$(a0 + a1 x + a2 x^2)(b0 + b1 x + b2 x^2)=$$

$$a0 b0 (C + 1 - x - x^2)$$
$$+ a1 b1 (C - x + x^2 - x^3)$$
$$ + a2 b2 (C - x^2 - x^3 + x^4)$$
$$ + (a0 + a1)(b0 + b1) (-C + x)$$
$$ + (a0 + a2)(b0 + b2) (-C + x^2)$$
$$ + (a1 + a2)(b1 + b2) (-C + x^3)$$
$$ + (a0+ a1 + a2)(b0 + b1 + b2) C$$

For an arbitrary polynomial $ C = C(x)$.
Hence picking $C$ conviently removes a factor therefore reducing the above $7$ to $6$.

Although this answers the OP partially it also rises questions.
Such as how many " C 's " are needed / possible for a given $f(n)$ ?
Is the highest number of C's NEC the best solution ?
Is there a closed form connection between $f(n)$ and the number of C ' s ?
Etc etc

I Will ask Some of them in a seperate thread.

Anyways knowledge of the required amount of C would greatly simplify my computations.

Thank you.

Comment: I have more results but im not confident they are optimal ( yet ).

Comment: We don't need optimal. Better than obvious is enough to make it interesting.

Comment: But the computations are hard.

Comment: Linked http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1888741/best-algoritm-for-multiplying-3-univariate-polynomials

Comment: One of the issues is why there are no internal products , meaning like ( a1^2 + 7 a2 + 1) * ...    Ofcourse that adds to the amount of products ... And substractions if they need to be cancelled. But still , they might reduce the Total number ??? Or not ? I searched mod 4 but im unaware of identities with nonunitcoefficients ...