# Best algoritm for multiplying 3 univariate polynomials?

Tags: polynomials, arithmetic, computational-complexity

Introduction

---

Karatsuba gave the optimal way for multiplying two polynomials of degree 1. He reduced the number of multiplications from 4 to 3.

Let the imput for f be the degree of a polynomial and the output the number of multiplications needed to multiply two such polynomials.

Thus

$$f(1)=3$$

And by iterating

$$f(2n−1)=<3n$$
That is karatsuba's result.

I recently discovered $f(2)$ is at most $6$.
( see answer at [Optimal multiplying method](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1886558/optimal-multiplying-method) )

I learned much about $f$ however ...

Questions

---

Let $g$ be the best algoritm to multiply 3 polynomials of degree $a,b,c$ and $f(u,V)$ the best algoritm to multiply 2 polynomials of degree $u,V$.

Conjecture 1

$f(u,V)$ is given by the same formula's for the $f( \max (u,V) ) $ but then by filling in the 0 coefficients the result is reduced and the number of multiplications is then optimal ( optimal reduced ).

Is the following pessimistic conjecture true ?

Conjecture 2

$$ g(a,b,c) = f(a,f(b,c)) = f(b,f(a,c)) = f(c,f(a,b))$$

Conjecture 3

If degree $a $ = $ b + c$  is then conjecture 2 true ?

Conjecture 4

$$g(a,b,c) = \min f(a,f(b,c)) , f(b,f(a,c)) , f(c,f(a,b))$$

Conjecture 5

Combining conjecture 3 and 4.

--- edit---

Conjecture 1 is completely false  !!
To my surprise !!

Seems conjecture 1 was too optimistic.
Is conjecture 2 too pessimistic ??

--- edit 2 ---

Added conjectures 3,4,5.

Comment: Hmm thinking about adding a conjecture ...

Comment: Maybe conjecture 1 is true afterall .... I made an error ...