# Analysis of a abstract function

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory

The known function $f:\mathbb{Z}^+ \to \mathbb{Z}^+$ is a monotone non decreasing function. For any coprime positive integers m and n satisfy $f(mn)=f(m)f(n)$. Compare the size of $f(2)f(8)$ and $f(3)f(5)$.

Comment: Thanks for your words,but I don't exactly know how to deal with it. I tried to find the relation between f(mn) and f(m)f(n) when m and n aren't coprime but failed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Paul Erdős showed that every increasing multiplicative arithmetic function $f:\mathbb{Z}_{>0}\to\mathbb{R}$ is of the form $$f(n)=n^\alpha$$ for all $n\in\mathbb{Z}_{>0}$ and $\alpha > 0$ is fixed.   A proof can be seen [here](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiJ1Ijlr6vcAhWSSH0KHfVYA30QFggoMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fservices.artofproblemsolving.com%2Fdownload.php%3Fid%3DYXR0YWNobWVudHMvMy9lLzAzODljZWU3ZjI4M2VjMGUyZDc0OTFlZWZiODc5Njk1NDljM2MxLnBkZg%3D%3D%26rn%3DRXJkb3MgVGhlb3JlbS5wZGY%3D&usg=AOvVaw0d8c9f14a1RggOX4lH_YaQ).  Here is another [link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1087910/a-result-of-erd%C5%91s-on-increasing-multiplicative-functions).

Comment: . . . nice . ..

Comment: Thanks, but I still don't know how to deal with "coprime" in this problem.

Comment: Why don't you read the article?  I gave you the link and, if you read it, you would see that it answers your question.

Comment: Sorry, I have a firewall in my country. I can't open the website you recommend.

Comment: Try searching for "monotone multiplicative arithmetic function" or something.  Maybe there will be a link you can access.  I added another link from stackexchange.

Comment: Thanks for your kindness!